# Sorting an array according to another array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have two arrays, the main includes something like 300 values:

```
var main = [ 182, 928, 192, 111, 493, 1100, 3 ] ..
```

The secondary includes 10 values, but each value is an array:

```
var secondary = [{"id" : 3, "category" : "animals"}, {"id" : 111, "category" : "water"}] ..
```

My question is how can I sort the **`secondary array`** by his id's according to the values in the **`main array`**?

Comment: You treat object as arrays. secondary should be something like that : var secondary = [{"id" : 3, "category" : "animals"}, {"id" : 111, "category" : "water"}];

Comment: I don't know javascript so I can't give you an answer, but please clarify: do you want to sort by id's, or by the values in the first array, or do you mean according to the order of id's in the first array?

Comment: @fusion - You RIGHT. it's not an objects, my false.

Comment: @ymett - according to the order of id's in the first array.

Comment: Oops.... it's not a duplicate...that was PHP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following code if you structure the second array as mentioned.
The solution uses indexOf which may not be present in all browsers. Mozilla provides an implementation for indexOf [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var main = [ 182, 928, 192, 111, 493, 1100, 3 ];
var secondary = [{"id" : 3, "category" : "animals"}, {"id" : 111, "category" : "water"}];

secondary.sort(function(a, b) {
    return main.indexOf(a["id"]) - main.indexOf(b["id"]);
});
```

Comment: Just note that calling `indexOf` for every comparison is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

First, create some kind of inverted index for the `main` array:

```
var main_map = {};
for(var i = main.length;i--; ) {
    main_map[main[i]] = i;
}
```

Then you can pass a custom sort function to [`sort` <sup>[docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this:

```
secondary.sort(function(a, b) {
    return main_map[a["id"]] - main_map[b["id"]];
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could create an inverted index for the `secondary` array and loop over the `main` array, but as your `secondary` array is much smaller, this would be less efficient.